# How to Make Play Button UI?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-sound

How to Make Play Button UI?
I'm Using This Module (https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound)
What Should I put in onPress or How to Play advertising.mp3` file?

```
 var whoosh = new Sound('advertising.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text title="mp3 in bundle" buttonLabel={'Play'} onPress={this.props.play(whoosh)} >Play</Text>
      </View >
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the examples here: https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound-demo/blob/master/main.js

Comment: Dear @d-reaper yes I can Play all example project and i can pause, But, That project is difficult for me, I Don't know, How to have simple play button, I opened This Issues Too(https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/230)